# Request a method to get the number of people following a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

How do I use the API to get the number of followers for a given tag?

On Stack Overflow, if you hover your mouse over a Tag a DHTML popup displays the number of followers for that tag.

I have used the Stacks Apps search as well as Google and can't find this piece of data in the APIs.  Am I missing something?

If "followers" is not a discoverable piece of data, consider this a feature request.  :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try below API methods, that might solve your requirement.

- **/tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}**

  Get the top answer posters in a specific tag, either in the last month or for all time.
- **/tags/{tag}/top-askers/{period}**

  Get the top question askers in a specific tag, either in the last month or for all time

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question or the OP's need. Please be careful when answering [feature-request] questions that (1) what is asked for may not be currently possible and (2) your answer helps resolve the stated problem.